# Вопрос по функции GetSysColor

Tags: c, windows, winapi, консоль

Пишу программу, которая должна выводить информацию о системе.

Задание звучит так:

> Написать программу для получения сведений о системе, используя функции
>   Win32 API: GetSystemInfo(), GetSysColor(), GetSystemMetrics().
>   Предусмотреть введение команд с клавиатуры.

Возникла проблема с выводом цветов (в программе - раздел *"Системные цвета"*) с помощью функции *GetSysColor()*, так как программа должна выводить цифру соответствующую цвету указанного отображаемого элемента. Но при компиляции выводятся постоянно *нули* с использованием параметров `COLOR_DESKTOP (= 1)`, `COLOR_WINDOWTEXT (= 8)`, а `COLOR_WINDOW (= 5)` выводит один и тот же набор цифр `16777215`.

Для проверки попробовал в персонализации ПК изменить цвет фона, но программа продолжает выводить те же значения.
Почитав документацию [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx), наткнулся на такой нюанс:

> The function returns the red, green, blue (RGB) color value of the
>   given element.
>
> If the nIndex parameter is out of range, the return value is zero.
>   Because zero is also a valid RGB value, you cannot use GetSysColor to
>   determine whether a system color is supported by the current platform.
>   Instead, use the GetSysColorBrush function, which returns NULL if the
>   color is not supported.

Для проверки того, что цвета поддерживаются или нет, решил проверить на других ПК, но результат остался тот же.

Почему функция `GetSysColor` выдает одни и те же значения для разных цветов?

Сам код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "iostream"
#include <windows.h> 
#include <string>
#include <VersionHelpers.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")


int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int count = 0;
    SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo; // Скопировать информацию об оборудовании в структуру SYSTEM_INFO.
    GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo); // Отображение содержимого структуры SYSTEM_INFO.

    printf("1.Информация о системе \n");
    printf("2.Системные метрики \n");
    printf("3.Системные цвета \n");

    printf("\n");
    printf("Введите число: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &count);
    printf("\n");
    system("cls");

    switch (count) {
    case 1:
        printf("Aппаратная информация: \n");
        printf("......................\n");
        printf("OEM-идентификатор: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwOemId);
        printf("Количество процессоров: %u\n",
            siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors);
        printf("Размер страницы: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwPageSize);
        printf("Тип процессора: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwProcessorType);
        printf("Минимальный адрес приложения: %p\n",
            siSysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
        printf("Максимальный адрес приложения: %p\n",
            siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress);
        printf("Маска активного процессора: %u\n",
            siSysInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Системные метрики: \n");
        printf("..................\n");
        printf("Разрешение экрана: %dx%d\n",
            GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1));
        printf("Ширина курсора в пикселях: %d\n",
            GetSystemMetrics(13));
        printf("Минимальная ширина окна в пикселях: %d\n",
            GetSystemMetrics(28));
        printf("Минимальная ширина окна в пикселях: %d\n",
            GetSystemMetrics(47));
        printf("Количество мониторов на рабочем столе: %d\n",
            GetSystemMetrics(80));
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("Системные цвета: \n");
        printf("................\n");
        printf("Цвет рабочего стола: %u\n",
            GetSysColor(1));
        printf("Текст в окнах: %u\n",
            GetSysColor(8));
        printf("Фон окна: %u\n",
            GetSysColor(5));
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Значение цифр: \n");
        printf("0 — черный\n");
        printf("1 — синий\n");
        printf("2 — зеленый\n");
        printf("3 — голубой\n");
        printf("4 — красный\n");
        printf("5 — лиловый\n");
        printf("6 — желтый\n");
        printf("7 — белый\n");
        printf("8 — серый\n");
        printf("9 — свело-синий\n");
        printf("A — светло-зеленый\n");
        printf("B — светло-голубой\n");
        printf("С — светло-красный\n");
        printf("E — светло-желтый\n");
        printf("F — ярко-белый\n");
        break;
    default: {
        printf("Error");
    }
}
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: А как ситуация с GetSysColorBrush()?

Comment: Это же у вас стандартные цвета для 16-цветных режимов, эпохи EGA адаптеров. Где вы такую древность раскопали? GetSysColor разумеется возвращает не это, как внизу верно ответили. А в качестве аргумента GetSysColor используйте символические имена, а не числовые константы. Чем избавляться от дурных привычек, лучше сразу их не заводить.

Comment: @freim, спасибо) 
да было дано задание, пытался таким образом реализовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы немного не то понимаете под возвращаемым этой функцией значением. Это не "1 - синий, 2 - зеленый...". Это выдача в виде RGB-байт, т.е. число, которое в 16-ричной записи имеет вид `bbggrr`, где `rr` - красная составляющая цвета, `gg` - зеленая и `bb` - синяя. Так что серый цвет имеет значение вроде `7f7f7f`. Да и цвета - не консольного окна, а, так сказать, обычного окна приложения.

Если подправить код как

```
printf("Цвет рабочего стола: %06X\n", GetSysColor(1));
printf("Текст в окнах: %06X\n",       GetSysColor(8));
printf("Фон окна: %06X\n",            GetSysColor(5));
```

то у меня, например, получается

```
Цвет рабочего стола: A56E3A
Текст в окнах: 000000
Фон окна: FFFFFF
```

Т.е. черный текст на белом фоне, ну, а цвет рабочего стола - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавьте для расшифровки цветов что-то вроде

```
printf("Красный - %02X, зеленый - %02X, синий - %02x\n",
       GetRValue(GetSysColor(1)),
       GetGValue(GetSysColor(1)),
       GetBValue(GetSysColor(1)));
```

Будет понятнее.

Comment: Благодарю за такой развернутый ответ! Приму к сведению ваши уточнения.

Answer (score 0):

Цвета можно  создавать getsolidbruh()
но получив контекст кисти его нужно после удалить а получая системный
цвет,точнее системный контекст цвета функцией GetSysColor()
его можно не удалять.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это просто дополнение или ответ на чьё-то  сообщение, а не полноценный ответ на вопрос. тогда стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос